# Do I need to have a perk on in order to get credit towards a pro perk?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In Call of Duty: Black Ops (PS3) do I need to have a perk activated in order to get credit towards a pro perk?

For example:  I want the Warlord Pro perk and I need to get 10 kills with a frag/semtex grenade.  What happens if I get all 10 kills without the Warlord perk activated.  Will those kills count towards getting Warlord Pro?

Answer (score 6):

You must have the base perk activated for the kills to count toward the pro perk.

Some supporting links:

- [codblackopsblog.com](http://www.codblackopsblog.com/call-of-duty-black-ops-perks-list/)
- [cod7blackops.com](http://www.cod7blackops.com/perks/)